# No se guardan los datos ingresados en formulario Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Luego de ingresar los datos en cada campo y de dar clic en el botón guardar, me dirige a la sección principal pero no me muestra el registro ni me lo guarda en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo dos modelos Reasignacion, Detallerea y un mismo request y controller para los dos ya que como se muestra en el formulario ambos modelos se relacionan. Aquí dejo el código del controller en la function de store que es donde se supone se deben almacenar los datos.

```
 public function store (ReasignacionFormRequest $request)
    {
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $reasignacion=new Reasignacion;
            $reasignacion->idpmed=$request->get('idpmed');
            $reasignacion->idprestador=$request->get('idprestador');
            $reasignacion->Medicamento=$request->get('Medicamento');
            $reasignacion->Tipo=$request->get('Tipo');
            $reasignacion->total=$request->get('total');

            $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Montevideo');
            $reasignacion->fecha_hora=$mytime->toDateTimeString();
            $reasignacion->estado='Activo';
            $reasignacion->save();

            $idexcedente = $request->get('idexcedente');
            $idprestador = $request->get('idprestador');
            $cantidad = $request->get('cantidad');

            $cont = 0;

            while($cont < count($idexcedente)){
                $detallerea = new Detallerea();
                $detallerea->idreasignacion= $reasignacion->idreasignacion; 
                $detallerea->idexcedente= $idexcedente[$cont];
                $detallerea->idprestador= $idprestador[$cont];
                $detallerea->cantidad= $cantidad[$cont];
                $detallerea->save();
                $cont=$cont+1;            
            }

            DB::commit();

        }catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            DB::rollback();
        }

        return Redirect::to('/reasignaciones');
    }
```

Y esto seria un fragmento del FormRequest

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [

         'idpmed'=>'required',
         'idprestador'=>'required',
         'Medicamento'=>'required|max:150',
         'Tipo_Solicitud'=>'required',
         'Total'=>'numeric',
         'idexcedente'=>'required',
         'Cantidad'=>'numeric'
        ];
    }
```

**Aquí esta la view del create.blade tiene una parte de js que no la subí, si es necesaria la subo**

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Nueva Reasignacion</h3>
            @if (count($errors)>0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
            {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'/reasignaciones','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
            {{Form::token()}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idpmed">C.I.</label>
                <select name="idpmed" id="idpmed" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    @foreach($pacientesm as $pac)
                     <option value="{{$pac->idpmed}}_{{$pac->Primer_Nombre}}_{{$pac->Primer_Apellido}}">{{$pac->CI}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Primer_Nombre">Primer Nombre</label>
                 <input type="text" disabled name="Primer_Nombre" id="Primer_Nombre" class="form-control"placeholder="Primer Nombre">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Primer_Apellido">Primer Apellido</label>
                 <input type="text" disabled name="Primer_Apellido" id="Primer_Apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Primer Apellido">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="idprestador">Prestador/Seguro</label>
                <select name="idprestador" id="idprestador" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    @foreach($prestador as $pre)
                     <option value="{{$pre->idprestador}}">{{$pre->Nombre}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Medicamento">Medicamento</label>
                <input type="text" name="Medicamento" value="{{old('Medicamento')}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Medicamento...">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Tipo_Solicitud">Tipo de Solicitud</label>
                <select name="Tipo_Solicitud" id="Tipo_Solicitud" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                    @foreach($tiposolicitud as $soli)
                     <option value="{{$soli->Tipo_Solicitud}}">{{$soli->Tipo_Solicitud}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Excedente</label>
                            <select name="pidexcedente" class="form-control selectpicker" id="pidexcedente" data-live-search="true">
                                @foreach($excedentes as $exc)
                                 <option value="{{$exc->idexcedente}}_{{$exc->stock}}">{{$exc->nombre}}</option>
                                 @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="idprestador">Custodia</label>
                            <select name="idprestador" id="custodia" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                @foreach($prestador as $pre)
                                 <option value="{{$pre->idprestador}}">{{$pre->Nombre}}</option>
                                 @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="stock">Stock</label>
                            <input type="number" disabled name="pstock" id="pstock" class="form-control" 
                            placeholder="Stock">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
                            <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="pcantidad" class="form-control" 
                            placeholder="Cantidad">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <button type="button" id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
                                <th style="text-align: center;">Opciones</th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;">Excedente</th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;">Custodia</th>
                                <th style="text-align: center;">Cantidad</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="3"></th>
                                    <th><p align="right"><span id="total">Comp/Amp: 000</span> <input type="hidden" name="total" id="total"></p></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="guardar">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" type="hidden"></input>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
            {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Si es necesario que agregue mas partes del código, favor de avisarme.

Comment: Podrias agregar tu html del formulario

Comment: agregada view create

Comment: Has probado a ver si te lanza alguna excepción el catch?

Comment: no me aparece nada, donde debería mirar eso? quizás estoy mirando mal

Comment: @Laude pon un dd($e->getMessage()); para ver si te da algún error dentro del catch.

Comment: @pwron lo puse y luego de probar guardar un registro me aparece una pantalla blanca con una linea negra en la parte superior y dentro en letras verdes dice: "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Asegúrate de que el método y la ruta (acción) del formulario se corresponden con la ruta adecuada de tu aplicación. Utiliza `php artisan route:list` para ver todas las rutas.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas Luego de agregarle el dd($e->getMessage()); al catch, ahora al darle clic a guardar me aparece una pantalla blanca con una linea negra en la parte superior y dentro en letras verdes dice: "Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es porque tienes más de un control con el mismo nombre: *idprestador*. Los valores que vienen con ese nombre están en un array, no en un string y de ahí el mensaje

Si necesitas que haya varios valores de ese tipo, tendrás que acceder así:

```
$reasignacion->idprestador = $request->get('idprestador')[0];
...
$idprestador = $request->get('idprestador')[1];
```

También puedes nombrarlos de modo distinto y así puede quedar más claro en el código